# switching between pages with tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a mini project for myself and I cant seem to find a way to discard the old UI when a button calls the new UI. All I want is for a way to switch between the pages while keeping what's initialized in my class and for it to discard the old page. I tried to look everywhere (stack overflow, youtube, google, etc) to see different solutions but nothing worked for me. I not sure what I can do.

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter import ttk

    class Cinema():
        def __init__(self, root):
            self.root = root
            title = Label(self.root, text="Bravo Cinema", font=("Helvetica", 40, "bold"), foreground="orange", background="#46464a").pack()
            
            #main navigation buttons
            self.movies = Button(self.root, text="View Movies", font=("Helvetica", 15), fg="orange", bg="#46464a", activeforeground="orange", activebackground="#2c2c2e", cursor="hand2",
                                 command = self.view_movies_UI)
            self.movies.place(x=30, y=110)

            self.add_movie = Button(self.root, text="Add Movie", font=("Helvetica", 15), fg="orange", bg="#46464a", activeforeground="orange", activebackground="#2c2c2e", cursor="hand2",
                                    command = self.add_movie_UI)
            self.add_movie.place(x=185, y=110)

            self.bookings = Button(self.root, text="View Bookings", font=("Helvetica", 15), fg="orange", bg="#46464a", activeforeground="orange", activebackground="#2c2c2e", cursor="hand2",
                                   command = self.view_bookings_UI)
            self.bookings.place(x=320, y=110)
            
        #view movies
        def view_movies_UI(self):
            #label
            lbl_all_movies = Label(self.root, text="All movies", font=("Helvetica", 13), bg="#46464a", fg="orange")
            lbl_all_movies.place(x=50, y=160)
            movies_frame = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
            movies_frame.place(x=50, y= 190)

            #tree view table
            movie_tree = ttk.Treeview(movies_frame, column=("#1", "#2"), show='headings')

            #columns and headings
            movie_tree.column("#1", anchor=CENTER, width=60)
            movie_tree.column("#2", anchor=CENTER, width=110)
            movie_tree.heading("#1", text="ID")
            movie_tree.heading("#2", text="Name")
            movie_tree.pack()

        #add movie
        def add_movie_UI(self):
            #entry boxes
            lbl_movie_name = Label(self.root, text="Movie Name:", font=("Ariel", 11), bg="#46464a", fg="white")
            lbl_movie_name.place(x=15, y=165)
            txt_movie_name = Entry(self.root, font=("Ariel", 10), width=40, bg="#46464a", fg="white")
            txt_movie_name.place(x=15, y=190)

            lbl_run_time = Label(self.root, text="Movie Length (minutes):", font=("Ariel", 11), bg="#46464a", fg="white")
            lbl_run_time.place(x=15, y=230)
            txt_run_time = Entry(self.root, font=("Ariel", 10), width=40, bg="#46464a", fg="white")
            txt_run_time.place(x=15, y=255)

            lbl_genre = Label(self.root, text="Movie Genre/Genres:", font=("Ariel", 11), bg="#46464a", fg="white")
            lbl_genre.place(x=15, y=290)
            txt_genre = Entry(self.root, font=("Ariel", 10), width=40, bg="#46464a", fg="white")
            txt_genre.place(x=15, y=315)

        #view bookings
        def view_bookings_UI(self):
            #label
            lbl_all_bookings = Label(self.root, text="All Bookings", font=("Helvetica", 13), bg="#46464a", fg="orange")
            lbl_all_bookings.place(x=50, y=160)
            bookings_frame = Frame(self.root, bg="white")
            bookings_frame.place(x=50, y= 190)

            #tree view table
            booking_tree = ttk.Treeview(bookings_frame, column=("#1"), show='headings')

            #columns and headings
            booking_tree.column("#1", anchor=CENTER, width=60)
            booking_tree.heading("#1", text="ID")
            booking_tree.pack()


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        root = Tk()
        root.geometry("700x700")
        root.title("Bravo Cinema")
        root.configure(background="#46464a")
        bravo = Cinema(root)
        root.mainloop()
```

I tried to mess around with frames in multiple (if that's either initializing the frame or creating a frame within the UI functions) ways but for some reason I cant place any widgets in the frame. I'd also like to keep my code in one class as I've seen solutions done with more than one class.

Example code would really help.

Comment: Make a New Frame. And place the buttons you want to delete inside that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new Frame. Place the buttons. And modify functions. Try this code -

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class Cinema():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        title = Label(self.root, text="Bravo Cinema", font=("Helvetica", 40, "bold"), foreground="orange", background="#46464a").pack()
        
        #main navigation buttons
        self.movies = Button(self.root, text="View Movies", font=("Helvetica", 15), fg="orange", bg="#46464a", activeforeground="orange", activebackground="#2c2c2e", cursor="hand2",
                             command = self.view_movies_UI)
        self.movies.place(x=30, y=110)

        self.add_movie = Button(self.root, text="Add Movie", font=("Helvetica", 15), fg="orange", bg="#46464a", activeforeground="orange", activebackground="#2c2c2e", cursor="hand2",
                                command = self.add_movie_UI)
        self.add_movie.place(x=185, y=110)

        self.bookings = Button(self.root, text="View Bookings", font=("Helvetica", 15), fg="orange", bg="#46464a", activeforeground="orange", activebackground="#2c2c2e", cursor="hand2",
                               command = self.view_bookings_UI)
        self.bookings.place(x=320, y=110)

        self.frame1 = Frame(self.root,background="#46464a")
        self.frame1.place(x=0,y=160)
        
    #view movies
    def view_movies_UI(self):
        #label

        try:

            for widget in self.frame1.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()

        except:
            pass
        
        lbl_all_movies = Label(self.frame1, text="All movies", font=("Helvetica", 13), bg="#46464a", fg="orange")
        lbl_all_movies.pack()
        movies_frame = Frame(self.frame1, bg="white")
        movies_frame.pack()

        #tree view table
        movie_tree = ttk.Treeview(movies_frame, column=("#1", "#2"), show='headings')

        #columns and headings
        movie_tree.column("#1", anchor=CENTER, width=60)
        movie_tree.column("#2", anchor=CENTER, width=110)
        movie_tree.heading("#1", text="ID")
        movie_tree.heading("#2", text="Name")
        movie_tree.pack()

    #add movie
    def add_movie_UI(self):

        try:

            for widget in self.frame1.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()

        except:
            pass

        
        #entry boxes
        lbl_movie_name = Label(self.frame1, text="Movie Name:", font=("Ariel", 11), bg="#46464a", fg="white")
        lbl_movie_name.pack()
        txt_movie_name = Entry(self.frame1, font=("Ariel", 10), width=40, bg="#46464a", fg="white")
        txt_movie_name.pack()

        lbl_run_time = Label(self.frame1, text="Movie Length (minutes):", font=("Ariel", 11), bg="#46464a", fg="white")
        lbl_run_time.pack()
        txt_run_time = Entry(self.frame1, font=("Ariel", 10), width=40, bg="#46464a", fg="white")
        txt_run_time.pack()

        lbl_genre = Label(self.frame1, text="Movie Genre/Genres:", font=("Ariel", 11), bg="#46464a", fg="white")
        lbl_genre.pack()
        txt_genre = Entry(self.frame1, font=("Ariel", 10), width=40, bg="#46464a", fg="white")
        txt_genre.pack()

    #view bookings
    def view_bookings_UI(self):

        try:

            for widget in self.frame1.winfo_children():
                widget.destroy()

        except:
            pass
        
        #label
        lbl_all_bookings = Label(self.frame1, text="All Bookings", font=("Helvetica", 13), bg="#46464a", fg="orange")
        lbl_all_bookings.pack()
        bookings_frame = Frame(self.frame1, bg="white")
        bookings_frame.pack()

        #tree view table
        booking_tree = ttk.Treeview(bookings_frame, column=("#1"), show='headings')

        #columns and headings
        booking_tree.column("#1", anchor=CENTER, width=60)
        booking_tree.heading("#1", text="ID")
        booking_tree.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x700")
    root.title("Bravo Cinema")
    root.configure(background="#46464a")
    bravo = Cinema(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

I used -

```
try:
    
     for widget in self.frame1.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()

except:
      pass
```

to delete the frame's content.

If you run this you will see that the old UI gets deleted.

(I have used `.pack()`, so the buttons may not be positioned the way you wanted them. So, change it such that it matches for you)

```
Edit:

If you want to use `.place()`, then you should give the frame a definite size like - `Frame(self.root,width=SOME_VALUE,height=SOME_VALUE)`

If you give a size then you can use `.place()` as needed (Give it some size such that it looks good. So, first change the frame's color to white, so that you can see for yourself the size of the frame and then modify the width and height)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helps a lot. But is there a way I can do this with the 'place' method? This is just so I can position everything the way I want. when I tried to run this code while the 'pack' is changed to 'place', the UI wouldn't show like expected.

Comment: I am actually gonna marry you, you have helped so much. As soon as I get more reputation points I will be sure to upvote your comments :)

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helps you by clicking the tick symbol :)